# Calling function in PHP

Tags: php, function, echo

I am trying to call a function called displaySentence() and have it output the value of the 'sentence' typed into the form on candycontest.php. The function will eventually have more features, but for now I am just trying to echo out the value of that sentence to ensure the function works. When I run the script, the pages displays until it gets to my function, at which point it is blank.

**candycontest.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pete's Treats Candy Contest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="checkticket.php" method="post">
        <label for="ticketNum">Enter your ticket number:</label>
        <input type="number" name="ticketNum" style="width:100px"><br/>
        <label for="sentence">Enter the magic sentence:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sentence" style="width:600px"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Am I a Winner?">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**checkticket.php**

```
<?php

$userTicket = $_POST['ticketNum'];


class MagicSentence {
public $sentence;


public function __construct($sentence) {
    $this->setSentence($sentence);
}

public function getSentence() { return $this->sentence; }
public function setSentence($sentence) {
    $this->sentence = $sentence;
}
} // End class MagicSentence



class Ticket extends MagicSentence {
public $ticketNum;

public function displaySentence() {
    $userSentence = $_POST['sentence'];
    echo $userSentence;
}
}

$magicSentence = new MagicSentence("The cow jumped over the moon.");
?>



<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pete's Treats Candy Contest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 


        echo 'Your ticket number is: ' . $userTicket . "<br>";
        echo 'The magic sentence is: ' . $magicSentence->getSentence() .     "<br>";

        displaySentence();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's header.php?

Comment: Why are you calling your class method as a function?

Comment: It's just some title info that would be the same on every page. It's not needed, so let me comment that line real quick.

Comment: As @akanevsky just pointed out, and I just figured out as well, that `displaySentence()` is a class method -- not a function

Comment: Eventually the function will accept an input and use that input to test its match against the $magicSentence object. For now I'm just trying to ensure the function works at all.

Comment: I'm trying to follow a lab that doesn't seem to be put together very well. In my lab I am supposed to create a public function within the Ticket class that will accept an input to test equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$magicSentence = new MagicSentence("The cow jumped over the moon.");` to `$magicSentence = new Ticket("The cow jumped over the moon.");`

You need to do this because the `displaySentence()` method exists under the `Ticket` class (which extends off the `MagicSentence` class).

Also, change `displaySentence();` to `$magicSentence->displaySentence();` in order to call your method. You cannot call a method as you would a regular function.

Do that and you should be golden.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of class `Ticket`, `$ticketObj` and use `$ticketObj->displaySentence();` in place of `displaySentence();`

Answer (score 0):

`displaySentence();` is a method of the `Ticket` class, of which you never instantiated an object, so it doesn't exist in any context yet.

`$magicSentence = new MagicSentence("The cow jumped over the moon.");`
needs to be:
`$magicSentence = new Ticket("The cow jumped over the moon.");`

and
`displaySentence();` needs to be: `$magicSentence->displaySentence();`